# ACF Maps admin error: "For development purposes only" even after supplying api key

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, google-maps

[image]

This issue is occurring even when I tried registering the key via various actions and filters.

**Fails**

Method 1:

```
function my_acf_init() {

  acf_update_setting('google_api_key', 'xxx');
}
add_action('acf/init', 'my_acf_init');
```

Method 2:

```
function my_acf_google_map_api( $api ){

  $api['key'] = 'xxx';

  return $api;

}

add_filter('acf/fields/google_map/api', 'my_acf_google_map_api');
```

Is there an extra step needed to ensure the map api key is included in the enqueued google map script on the admin side of WordPress?

**Edit:** THIS KEY WORKS FOR THE MAPS ON THE FRONT END OF THE WEBSITE

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have not entered payment information to your Google Developer Account. While you get 200$ of API Calls "for free", you have to enter payment information to your developer Account for when you go over these "free" API Calls.